# How to show error and success message in laravel using version 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, popup, message

I want to display my success and error message on my popup model i have setup session message for success and danger on my view but its redirecting me back to my page as there is condition in my controller but i want to show these success and error messages on my model:

My popup form:

```
                    <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form" id="passwordchangeform" class="common_form_style popup_form" method="POST" novalidate action="{{ url('/changepassword') }}">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password" style="width:100%">PÅ¯vodnÃ­ heslo </label>
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                                <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="new_password" style="width:100%">NovÄ› heslo</label>
                                <input id="new_password" type="password" class="form-control" name="new_password">
                                <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                                <span class="help-block" style="color:#737373;font-size:14px;float:right;margin-right: 30px;font-weight: 100 !important;">MinimÃ¡lnÄ› 8 znakÅ¯, jedno velkÃ© a malÃ© pÃ­smeno a ÄÃ­slo</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="heslo znovu">PotvrzenÃ­ heslo</label>
                                <input id="password_confirmation" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">
                                <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="submit-btn text-center">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default chci" style="background:#e94549;">UloÅ¾it</button>
                            </div>
                            <div style="margin-top:10px;" id="success-messages"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 pull-right"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

and my controller:

```
                $current_password = $user->password;
        if(md5($request_data['password']) == $current_password) {
            $user_id = $user->id;
            $obj_user = User::find($user_id);
            $obj_user->password = md5($request_data['new_password']);;
            $obj_user->save();

            $data = array('info_success'  => "Password has been changed!", 'tab'   => '');
            return redirect('mujucet')->with($data);
        } else {
            $error = array('non-success' => "Heslo, které jste zadali, je neplatné.", 'tab'   => '');
           return redirect('mujucet')->with($error);
        }
```

I want to show messages on my pop how i can do that
Your help need here!

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that nowhere within your view you're using the variables you're sending from the controller. Add this and it should function as expected:

```
//Assuming blade & bootstrap in this case:
@if(isset($info_success ))
   <div class="col-xs-12">
     <div class="alert alert-success">
       <b>Success:</b>{{ $info_success }}
     </div>
  </div>
@elseif(isset($non_success))
  <div class="col-xs-12">
     <div class="alert alert-danger">
       <b>Error:</b>{{ $non_success }}
     </div>
  </div>
@endif
```